# Clear buffer stdin

Tags: c

Hello Stackoverflow community, I have a problem with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50


int main()
{
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_SIZE);
    do{
        int r = read(STDIN_FILENO, s, MAX_SIZE);
        if(r==-1) printf("error");
        else{
            write(STDERR_FILENO, s, MAX_SIZE);
        }
        while(getchar()!='\n');
    } while(strcmp(s,"end\n")!=0);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it produces me a wrong output, stdin doesn't results "clean" at each iteration of the 'do while'. I know that on windows i must use `fflush(stdin)` but watching on internet i saw that this function is not portable for linux. i use linux, and always watching on internet i saw that many people say the solution is `while(getchar()!='\n);` instead of `fflush(stdin)`, but the problem is not resolved... Can you explain me why?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behaviour, doesn't it?

Comment: Consider tagging this question with C instead of C++, as far as I can tell this is a C program not a C++ program?

Comment: my bad, sorry...then fflush(stdin) should be an undefined behaviour ?

Comment: Don't call read() and write() - use stdc library calls fgets(), printf().  The problem is that  you have clear the "s" variable - set all 50 bytes to 0x0.  The read & write functions ignore the ascii 0 at the end of a C string and just plow on ahead all the way to 50 bytes of garbage.

Comment: This should solve my problem?

Comment: Yeah - either memset the s variable to all 0x0, inside the loop or use stdc calls.  stdc is a better choice for this

Comment: Don't mix Unix-style IO with stdio for the same stream. Nothing good can possibly result.

Comment: Side note: `sizeof(char)` is always one

Comment: Do not edit your question to remove it when you have an answer. What if someone in the future has a similar issue?

Comment: Odd why nothing happens when I pressed the 'rollback' link on revision 5 of this post....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems that I see:

1. You are passing the wrong argument to `write`. Instead of

   ```
   write(STDERR_FILENO, s, MAX_SIZE);
   ```

   it should be

   ```
   write(STDERR_FILENO, s, r); // Write the number of characters that were read
                               // not MAX_SIZE
   ```
2. The strategy to skip till the end of the line is not well thought out. You have:

   ```
   int r = read(STDIN_FILENO, s, MAX_SIZE);
   if(r==-1) printf("error");
   else{
       write(STDERR_FILENO, s, MAX_SIZE);
   }
   while(getchar()!='\n');
   ```

   First of all, `read` will not stop reading when it encounters a newline. It will read up to `MAX_SIZE` characters. It will gobble up as many newlines as it can in the process. What you need to do is use `fgets()` instead.

   ```
   char* cp = fgets(s, MAX_SIZE, stdin);
   if ( cp == NULL )
   {
      // If fgets fails, you probably reached the end of the file.
      break;
   }

   fprintf(stderr, "%s", s);
   ```
3. The line

   ```
   while(strcmp(s,"end\n")!=0);
   ```

   will lead to undefined behavior if you use `read` to read the data from a file since `read` does not automatically add a terminating null character to `s`. Using `fgets` avoids that problem.

Also, since you know the size of the array at compile time, you can use:

```
char s[MAX_SIZE];
```

instead of using `malloc` to allocate memory at run time.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, an equivalent C++ program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
        if (line == "end")
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The c++ tag has been removed. Better remove your answer.